# Traefik doesn't append prefix to a redirect location

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am using an open-source custom service for Prometheus. My goal is to make it available under example.com/customservice endpoint.

While I was able to make it available through Traefik ingress controller, the service itself makes a redirect (301 HTTP code) to a different endpoint.

For example, if I send a request to example.com/customservice/livenessProble it must go to example.com/customservice/alive. The problem is that it redirects to example.com/alive, which doesn't exist and gives me the 404 error.

How do I configure Traefik (or the Ingress controller) to make this redirect to a proper subpath?

Ingress controller:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
{{ include "common-labels" . | indent 4 }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-insecure: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: "http,https"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: "PathPrefixStrip:/customservice"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/customservice"
  name: {{ include "name" . | quote }}
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  # tls:
  # - hosts:
  #     - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /customservice
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ include "name" . | quote }}
            port:
              number: 8881
```

curl debug message:

```sh
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55740a331860)
> GET /customservice/livenessProbe HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
< HTTP/2 301 
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< date: Mon, 14 Feb 2022 14:08:12 GMT
< location: /alive
< content-length: 41
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://example.com/alive'
* Found bundle for host example.com: 0x55740a325a70 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host example.com
* Connected to example.com (10.211.2.191) port 443 (#0)
* Using Stream ID: 3 (easy handle 0x55740a331860)
> GET /alive HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/2 404 
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< content-length: 19
< date: Mon, 14 Feb 2022 14:08:12 GMT
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

traefik logs:

```sh
IP - - [14/Feb/2022:14:55:53 +0000] "GET /customservice/livenessProbe HTTP/1.1" 301 41 "-" "-" 6898650 "xxx@customservice" "http://IP_ADDRESS:8080" 2ms
IP - - [14/Feb/2022:14:55:53 +0000] "GET /alive HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 6898651 "-" "-" 0ms
```

UPD:

```sh
user@server:~$ k version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.2", GitCommit:"8b5a19147530eaac9476b0ab82980b4088bbc1b2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.9", GitCommit:"9dd794e454ac32d97cde41ae10be801ae98f75df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:00:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Kubernetes is installed in a VM that is running in OpenStack.

Comment: Could you please give more details about your Kubernetes environment - version of Kubernetes, is it bare metal installation or on cloud provider? How exactly is Prometheus configured?

Comment: Added at the end of the question. Prometheus doesn't matter here - I am testing it with curl.